# extending hashmap + serializeable issue

Tags: android, serialization, hashmap

I extended hashmap (say, MyClass):

```
public class MyClass extends HashMap<String, String>
 {
   // something
 }
```

Now, in an activity I put object of this class to extras (I can do it since HashMap is serializeable):

Activity A:

```
  MyClass myClass=new MyClass();
  ...
  Intent i = getIntent();
            i.putExtra("key", myClass);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
```

And in activity B (in onActivityResult) I retrieve the value back:

```
  Object o=data.getSerializableExtra("key");
```

My problem is that o is not MyClass, but HashMap. I want it to be MyClass, but I get ClassCastException whenever I suppose o to be instance of MyClass:

```
  MyClass o=(MyClass) data.getSerializableExtra("key");
```

Why it returns superclass instance?

Stack:

```
07-06 18:32:58.539: E/AndroidRuntime(25268): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap
07-06 18:32:58.539: E/AndroidRuntime(25268):    at ...Search.onActivityResult(Search.java:158)
07-06 18:32:58.539: E/AndroidRuntime(25268):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
07-06 18:32:58.539: E/AndroidRuntime(25268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
```

Comment: Can you post full stack of ClassCastException message?

Comment: You are casting as MyClass o=(MyClass) data.getSerializableExtra("key");  **Instead that use** HashMap<String, String> myClass= (HashMap<String, String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");

Comment: further methods which I pass myClass to accept MyClass not HashMap. So it is crucial to me myClass to be instance of MyClass.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to extend `HashMap`. Instead extend `AbstractMap` or Guava's `ForwardingMap`. Even better, prefer [composition to inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and define your own type that *contains* a `Map` rather than *implements* `Map`. The problems you're running into here are a classic example of over-using inheritance.